# How to access a value within the body of html using soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to access the live price of a crypto currency coin from an exchange webpage through python.

The XPath of the value I want is in `/html/body/luno-exchange-app/luno-navigation/div/luno-market/div/section[2]/luno-orderbook/div/luno-spread/div/luno-orderbook-entry[2]/div/span/span` and I have been doing the following

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
exchage_url = 'https://www.luno.com/trade/markets/LTCXBT'
uClient = uReq(exchange_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
print(page_soup.html.body.luno-exchange-app.luno-navigation.div.luno-market.div.section[2].luno-orderbook.div.luno-spread.div.luno-orderbook-entry[2].div.span.span)
```

However the code doesn't work, due to the '-' in `print(page_soup.html.body.luno-exchange-app...)`

Is there a way to get that value I want?

How I got the XPath:
I pressed F12, right click the red box, and clicked "Inspect" which highlights a section in the html which I then right click, copy -> XPath. Here is a picture to visually show the value I want [The value I am interested in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s52Zk.png)

Comment: Please can you visually show where that price is as your xpath does not work for me and I see nothing labelled as live price.

Comment: I have updated the post with a picture to show how I got the XPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is dynamically added from an ajax request

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://ajax.luno.com/ajax/1/ticker?pair=LTCXBT')
print(r.json()['bid'])
```